# Помогите сделать стиль кнопки

Tags: css, button

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста сделать стильно такой кнопки. Начал осваивать HTML и CSS, но с кнопками всегда были проблемы

[image: Нужно вот такую кнопку]

Answer (score 2):

```css
button{
  color: white;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #1E8AFA, #298EFF);
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #DBEBFF;
}
```

```html
<button>Показать историю</button>
```